# PHP: Icecast Now Playing Script is Not Working

Tags: php, icecast

I am attempting to use the Icecast Now Playing PHP script from: https://code.google.com/p/icecast-now-playing-script/

I have uploaded all the files to my web server after modifying the config.php. When I load example.php in the browser, this is the information returned:

```
Array (
    [info] => Array
        (
            [status] => OFF AIR
        )

)
```

I am not sure what the cause of the problem is. I have verified the Icecast server information is correct. Opening: `http://70.35.120.203:8000/zedg_mb.mp3.m3u` does start the stream playing. Here is the code:

Example.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title>Icecast Now Playing Script</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Code by Jude (<a href="mailto:surftheair@gmail.com">surftheair@gmail.com</a>)
</p>

<pre>
<?php
include('icecast.php');
print_r($stream);
?>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Config.php

```
<?php

//error_reporting(0);
define(SERVER, 'http://70.35.120.203:8000');//your icecast server address, without the ending "/"
define(MOUNT, '/zedg_mb.mp3.m3u'); //your radio's mount point, with the leading "/"
define(LAST_FM_API, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); //your last.fm API key, get from http://www.last.fm/api/account
define(DEFAULT_ALBUM_ART, 'http://www.channelztheedge.com/_images/others/othersZEDG-150sqd.png');//the default album art image, will be used if failed to get from last.fm's API
define(GET_TRACK_INFO, true); //get information of the current song from last.fm
define(GET_ALBUM_INFO, true); //get extra information of the album from last.fm, if enabled, may increase script execute time
define(GET_ARTIST_INFO, true); //get extra information of the artist from last.fm, if enabled, may increase script execute time
define(GET_TRACK_BUY_LINK, false); //get buy links on Amazon, iTune and 7digital
define(GET_LYRICS, true); //get lyrics of the current song using chartlyrics.com's API
define(CACHE_ALBUM_ART, true);//cache album art images to local server
define(RECORD_HISTORY, true);//record play history of your radio


?>
```

icecast.php

```
<?php 
/*
        by Jude <surftheair@gmail.com>
        http://jude.im/
        works with Icecast 2.3.2
*/

require('config.php');
$stream = getStreamInfo();
if($stream['info']['status'] == 'OFF AIR'){
        cacheVar($stream);
}
else{
        $last_song = @file_get_contents('last.txt');
        if($last_song != base64_encode($stream['info']['song'])){
                $stream = init($stream);
                $stream = getInfo($stream);
                file_put_contents('last.txt', base64_encode($stream['info']['song']));
                cacheVar($stream);
                if(RECORD_HISTORY == true){
                        cacheHistory($stream);
                }
        }
        else{
                $stream = array_decode(json_decode(@file_get_contents('var/info.json'), TRUE));
        }
}
//print_r($stream);

function obj_to_array($obj){
        $array = (is_object) ? (array)$obj : $obj;
        foreach($array as $k=>$v){
                if(is_object($v) OR is_array($v))
                        $array[$k] = obj_to_array($v);
        }
        return $array;
}

function getStreamInfo(){
        $str = @file_get_contents(SERVER.'/status.xsl?mount='.MOUNT);
        if(preg_match_all('/<td\s[^>]*class=\"streamdata\">(.*)<\/td>/isU', $str, $match)){
                $stream['info']['status'] = 'ON AIR';
                $stream['info']['title'] = $match[1][0]; 
                $stream['info']['description'] = $match[1][1]; 
                $stream['info']['type'] = $match[1][2]; 
                $stream['info']['start'] = $match[1][3]; 
                $stream['info']['bitrate'] = $match[1][4]; 
                $stream['info']['listeners'] = $match[1][5]; 
                $stream['info']['msx_listeners'] = $match[1][6]; 
                $stream['info']['genre'] = $match[1][7]; 
                $stream['info']['stream_url'] = $match[1][8];
                $stream['info']['artist_song'] = $match[1][9];
                        $x = explode(" - ",$match[1][9]); 
                $stream['info']['artist'] = $x[0]; 
                $stream['info']['song'] = $x[1];
        }
        else{
                $stream['info']['status'] = 'OFF AIR';
        }
        return $stream;
}

//get information of the current song use last.fm's API
function getTrackInfo($stream){
        $url = str_replace('#','','http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getinfo&artist='.urlencode($stream['info']['artist']).'&track='.urlencode($stream['info']['song']).'&api_key='.LAST_FM_API);
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        $xml = obj_to_array($xml);
//      print_r($xml);
        if($xml['track']['album']['image']){
                $stream['album']['image_s'] = $xml['track']['album']['image'][0];
                $stream['album']['image_m'] = $xml['track']['album']['image'][1];
                $stream['album']['image_l'] = $xml['track']['album']['image'][2];
                $stream['album']['image_xl'] = $xml['track']['album']['image'][3];
        }
        if($xml['track']['wiki']['summary']){
                $stream['track']['summary'] = $xml['track']['wiki']['summary'];
                $stream['track']['info'] = $xml['track']['wiki']['content'];
        }
        if($xml['track']['album']['title']){
                $stream['album']['title'] = $xml['track']['album']['title'];
                $stream['album']['lastfm_url'] = $xml['track']['album']['url'];
        }
        $stream['track']['lastfm_url'] = $xml['track']['url'];
        if($xml['track']['artist']['url']){
                $stream['artist']['lastfm_url'] = $xml['track']['artist']['url'];
        }
        return $stream;
}

//get extra information of the album
function getAlbumInfo($stream){
        $url = str_replace('#','', 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&artist='.urlencode($stream['info']['artist']).'&album='.($stream['album']['title']).'&api_key='.LAST_FM_API);
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        $xml = obj_to_array($xml);
        if ($xml['album']['releasedate'] && strlen($xml['album']['releasedate']) > 10){
                $stream['album']['releasedate'] = reset(explode(",",$xml['album']['releasedate']));
        }
        if($xml['album']['tracks']['track']){
                foreach($xml['album']['tracks']['track'] as $track){
                        $stream['album']['track_list'][] = array('title' => $track['name'],'url' => $track['url']);
                }
        }
        if($xml['album']['wiki']['summary']){
                $stream['album']['summary'] = $xml['album']['wiki']['summary'];
                $stream['album']['info'] = $xml['album']['wiki']['content'];
        }
        return $stream;
}

//get extra information of the artist           
function getArtistInfo($stream){
        $url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&artist='.urlencode($stream['info']['artist']).'&api_key='.LAST_FM_API.'&autocorrect=1';
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        $xml = obj_to_array($xml);
//      print_r($xml);
        if($xml['topalbums']['album']){
                foreach($xml['topalbums']['album'] as $album){
                        $stream['artist']['top_albums'][] = array('title'=>$album['name'], 'url'=>$album['url'], 'image'=>$album['image']);
                }
        }

        $url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getInfo&artist='.urlencode($stream['info']['artist']).'&api_key='.LAST_FM_API.'&autocorrect=1';
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        $xml = obj_to_array($xml);
//      print_r($xml);
        if($xml['artist']['bio']['summary']){
                $stream['artist']['summary'] = $xml['artist']['bio']['summary'];
                $stream['artist']['info'] = $xml['artist']['bio']['content'];
        }
        return $stream;
}

//get buylink   
function getTrackBuyLink($stream){
        $url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getbuylinks&artist='.urlencode($stream['info']['artist']).'&track='.urlencode($stream['info']['song']).'&api_key='.LAST_FM_API.'&country='.urlencode('united states').'&autocorrect=1';
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        $xml = obj_to_array($xml);
//      print_r($xml);
        if($xml['affiliations']['physicals']['affiliation']){
                foreach($xml['affiliations']['physicals']['affiliation'] as $buy){
                        $supplier = str_replace('iTuens', 'iTunes', $buy['supplierName']);
                        if($buy['isSearch'] == 0){
                                $new = array('link' => $buy['buyLink'], 'price'=>$buy['price']['amount'], 'currency'=>$buy['price']['currency'], 'icon'=>$buy['supplierIcon']);
                        }
                        else{
                                $new = array('link' => $buy['buyLink'],'icon'=>$buy['supplierIcon']);
                        }
                        $stream['track']['buylink']['physical'][$supplier] = $new;
                }
        }
        if($xml['affiliations']['downloads']['affiliation']){
                foreach($xml['affiliations']['downloads']['affiliation'] as $buy){
                        $supplier = str_replace('Amazon MP3', 'Amazon', $buy['supplierName']);
                        if($buy['isSearch'] == 0){
                                $new = array('link' => $buy['buyLink'], 'price'=>$buy['price']['amount'], 'currency'=>$buy['price']['currency'], 'icon'=>$buy['supplierIcon']);
                        }
                        else{
                                $new = array('link' => $buy['buyLink'],'icon'=>$buy['supplierIcon']);
                        }
                        $stream['track']['buylink']['download'][$supplier] = $new;
                }
        }
        return $stream;
}


//cache album art images to local server, change the image size if you want
function cacheAlbumArt($image_url){
        $filename = end(explode('/', $image_url));
        $local_image = 'cache/'.$filename;
        if (!is_file($stream['album']['local_image'])){
                copy($image_url, $local_image);
        }
        return $local_image;
}

//get lyrics from chartlyrics.com's API
function getLyric($artist, $song){
        $url = str_replace('\'','','http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/SearchLyricDirect?artist='.urlencode($artist).'&song='.urlencode($song));
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        $xml = obj_to_array($xml);
//      print_r($xml);
        if($xml['LyricId'] && ($xml['Lyric'] != array())){
                return $xml['Lyric'];
        }
        else{
                return 'Sorry, there\'s no lyric found for this song';
        }
}

function getInfo($stream){
        if(!$stream['info']['song']){
                $stream['info']['song'] == 'Not found';
                return $stream;
        }
        if(GET_TRACK_INFO == TRUE){
                $stream = getTrackInfo($stream);
        }
        if(GET_ALBUM_INFO && isset($stream['album']['title'])){
                $stream = getAlbumInfo($stream);
        }
        if(GET_ARTIST_INFO == TRUE){
                $stream = getArtistInfo($stream);
        }
        if(GET_TRACK_BUY_LINK == TRUE){
                $stream = getTrackBuyLink($stream);
        }
        if(CACHE_ALBUM_ART == TRUE){
                $stream['album']['local_image'] = cacheAlbumArt($stream['album']['image_l']);
        }
        if(GET_LYRICS == TRUE){
                $stream['track']['lyric'] = getLyric($stream['info']['artist'], $stream['info']['song']);
        }
        $stream['fetch_time'] = time();
        return $stream;
}

function array_encode($array){
        foreach($array as $key=>$value){
                if(is_array($value)){
                        $array[$key] = array_encode($value);
                }
                else{
                        $array[$key] = base64_encode($value);
                }
        }
        return $array;
}

function array_decode($array){
        foreach($array as $key=>$value){
                if(is_array($value)){
                        $array[$key] = array_decode($value);
                }
                else{
                        $array[$key] = base64_decode($value);
                }
        }
        return $array;
}

function cacheVar($stream){
        $stream = array_encode($stream);
        file_put_contents('var/info.json', json_encode($stream));
}

function cacheHistory($stream){
        if($stream['song'] == 'Not found'){
                return;
        }
        $year = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');
        $day = date('d');
        if(!is_dir('history')){
                mkdir('history', 0777);
        }
        if(!is_dir('history/'.$year)){
                mkdir('history/'.$year);
        }
        if(!is_dir('history/'.$year.'/'.$month)){
                mkdir('history/'.$year.'/'.$month);
        }
        $file = 'history/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$day.'.json';
        $history['time'] = gmdate('c');
        $history['artist'] = $stream['info']['artist'];
        $history['song'] = $stream['info']['song'];
        $history['image'] = $stream['album']['image_s'];
        $history['itunes'] = $stream['track']['buylink']['download']['iTunes']['link'];
        $history['Amazon'] = $stream['track']['buylink']['download']['Amazon']['link'];
        $history = array_encode($history);
        file_put_contents($file, json_encode($history));
        createHistory();
}

function createHistory(){
        $history = json_decode(@file_get_contents('var/history.json'), TRUE);
        $year = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');
        $day = date('d');
        $history[$year][$month][$day] = $year.$month.$day;
        $file = 'history/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$day.'.json';
        file_put_contents('var/history.json', json_encode($history));
}


function init($stream){
        $stream['album']['image_s'] = $stream['album']['image_m'] = $stream['album']['image_l'] = $stream['album']['image_xl'] = DEFAULT_ALBUM_ART;
        $stream['track']['summary']  = $stream['track']['info'] = "No information found for this track, try searching for <a target='_blank' href='http://www.google.com/search?q=".urlencode($stream['info']['artist']." - ".$stream['info']['song'])."'>".$stream['info']['artist']." - ".$stream['info']['song']."</a> on Google";
        $stream['album']['title'] = 'Not found';
        $stream['album']['lastfm_url'] = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='.urlencode($stream['info']['artist']." - ".$stream['info']['song']);
        $stream['track']['download_cn'] = 'http://www.google.cn/music/search?q='.urlencode($stream['info']['artist']." - ".$stream['info']['song']);
        $stream['album']['summary'] = $stream['album']['info'] = 'No information found for this album, try searching for <a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/search?q='.urlencode($stream['info']['artist']." - ".$stream['info']['song']).'">'.$stream['info']['artist']." - ".$stream['info']['song'].'</a> on Google';
        $stream['album']['releasedate'] = 'Unknown';
        $stream['artist']['summary'] = $stream['artist']['info'] = 'No information found for this artist, try searching for <a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/search?q='.urlencode($stream['info']['artist']).'">'.$stream['info']['artist'].'</a> on Google';
        return $stream;
}

?>
```

I am quite new to PHP and am not understanding the instructions fully. Here are the instructions as posted:

> How to use the script on your own site:
>
> Get an API key from last.fm: http://www.last.fm/api/account Get the
>   script, edit the config file (config.php) Use the available variables
>   to echo what you want, there's also a list of available variables on
>   this wiki page:
>   code.google.com/p/icecast-now-playing-script/wiki/Variables Upload the
>   scripts to your webspace which support PHP, Change the attribute of the script >directory to be writable("666" for example)

**UPDATE**
Using the advice of GView and removing the '@' in front of file_get_contents and calling var_dump($str) returns this error:

```
 Warning:  file_get_contents(http://70.35.120.203:8000/status.xsl?mount=/zedg_mb.mp3.m3u) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection refused in /home/content/14/7785714/html/NowPlaying/icecast.php on line 40

bool(false)
Array
(
    [info] => Array
        (
            [status] => OFF AIR
        )

)       Please! Does anyone have any suggestions?
```

Comment: mistake #1: using a regex to parse html.

Comment: Might not be good to be posting your API key publicly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your server is not allowing HTTP stream wrappers.

In the icecast.php script the function getStreamInf() is being called and at the top it attempts to open the stream with:

```
$str = @file_get_contents(SERVER.'/status.xsl?mount='.MOUNT);
```

To debug this, do 2 things.  First remove the @ which suppresses error output on the file_get_contents call.  Then add temporary debugging output:

```
$str = file_get_contents(SERVER.'/status.xsl?mount='.MOUNT);
var_dump($str);
```

If you get a security related error, rather than data back, then you need to look at your php.ini file for the server.

```
allow_url_fopen = on
```

Needs to be set for file_get_contents to be able to open a url, as this script attempts to do.  You have to be able to change that setting on your server, if it is set to off, and you have to be able to restart your web server for those changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the API advice.

Comment: Thank you GView for you comment. I called GoDaddy and had them modify the php.ini: allow_irl_fopen to "on". I ran the example.php file again in my browser and the same information is displayed: ï»¿
Code by Jude (surftheair@gmail.com)    Do you have any other thoughts? This is driving me crazy. Thanks again for your help!

Array
(
    [info] => Array
        (
            [status] => OFF AIR
        )

)

Comment: I just noticed that you are getting the warning:  Warning:  file_get_contents(http://70.35.120.203:8000/status.xsl?mount=/zedg_mb.mp3.m3u) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection refused in /home/content/14/7785714/html/NowPlaying/icecast.php on line 40

Comment: In other words, your script isn't able to connect to the ice cast server and get the information.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that I would strongly advice not using the "Icecast Now Playing Script"!
**tl;dr**: It parses the HTML, this is horrible.

1. The script uses regex to parse the Icecast status.xsl page, never ever should Regex be used to parse HTML, if you want to know why, read ["Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/). It is very likely that it can break easily.
2. The script parses the Icecast status.xsl page. This should never ever be done, since this page is likely to change, like it did with the latest Icecast Version 2.4. So **please, please, please** do **not parse the HTML page**!

#### What to do instead?

If this is your Icecast Server, you can easily write a custom xsl, to generate custom XML or JSON that contains the information that you need. (more info [here](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.0/admin-interface.html#web-based-admin-interface))

An example for this is the [`xml2json.xslt`](http://svn.xiph.org/icecast/tags/icecast-2.4.0/web/xml2json.xslt).

Comment: And if you don't have control over the Icecast server, this PHP script in this guy's question uses the actual metadata stream instead of the status.xsl page!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803441/php-script-to-extract-artist-title-from-shoutcast-icecast-stream