# Icecast current listeners php script

Tags: icecast

I am searching for a script that echo out the current listeners.
but the script must look at two moint points of one server.
So it adds up.
Thanks in advance

Comment: That's rather trivial. Use a JSON parser in PHP to digest /status-json.xsl from the server and then add two numbers…

Comment: tried this script, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489773/use-php-to-show-icecast2-statistics but i cannot change it to two mount points